# how to iterate through an object to make all string values lowercase?

Tags: javascript

As the title states, I would like to write a function that takes an object and makes all of its string values lowercase. I am not sure why the code below does not return the intended result.

```js
let k1 = {
  spoons: "fOuR",
  forks: 3,
  knives: "ONE",
  cups: false
}

function sortTheKitchen(kitchen) {
  for (let x in kitchen) {
    if (typeof kitchen[x] === "string") {
      kitchen[x].toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  return kitchen;
}

console.log(sortTheKitchen(k1));
```

Comment: you are not assigning updated value to object key.

Comment: x=kitchen[x].toLowerCase();

Comment: how would that look with the updated object key?

Comment: In JS, strings are primitives, and are immutable, which means you cannot change the actual characters using a function like toLowerCase(). However, you can reassign the whole string to the return value of that function. So you can do: kitchen[x] = kitchen[x].toLowerCase()